# PHP hangs on date calculations

Tags: php, date, raspberry-pi

Lately any date operations or calculations in my script hangs until it is killed for taking too long (`Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded` error). It happens both running the script from Apache or on the command line. All of the date and date/time operations used to work.

The code that hangs can be as simple as `new DateTime()` or `date('Y')`, although `time()` does work.

I'm running PHP 5.6 on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Jessie with Apache 2.4.10.

The only date-related change to the system that I can think of is that I added an [RTC module](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3295) and followed the steps in the [Adafruit tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/adding-a-real-time-clock-to-raspberry-pi) to configure it. I don't know how that would have affected PHP though. Python's `time.localtime()` and just a plain ol' `date` or `hwclock` on the command line still work as expected.

Edit: I noticed that if I leave the command-line version running and watch it with `top`, PHP uses 100% of the CPU and the RAM usage increases steadily.

Update: I rolled back the configuration to not use the RTC module anymore, disabled I2C, and reinstalled fake-hwclock. The problem persists. Running `php -r 'echo date("Y");'` takes all the CPU and slowly takes all the RAM until manually killed. The problem doesn't appear to be related to the hardware RTC module.

Comment: Can you check this code `$curDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");

$dt = new DateTime($curDate);

echo $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") ;`

Comment: @Hackerman That also hangs.

Comment: I tested that code in an online php fiddle and it works...can you post the output of the apache error log? It should be in /var/log/httpd/error_log or in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: This is really weird... if time() works then date() SHOULD work.... can you try date('Y', time());? Does anyone know if PHP's date() derives value from OS or internally?

Comment: @Hackerman: `[Wed Nov 29 17:27:05.142556 2017] [:error] [pid 6735] [client 192.168.1.216:43181] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/php/events.php on line 39`. Line 39 is `$eventStart = strtotime($eventStartDate);`.

Comment: @PhillipWeber: Same result with `date("Y", time());`

Comment: @JonathanDean whats the value of eventstartdate

Comment: @PhillipWeber eventStartDate is "2017-11-27 12:00:00"

Comment: hrmmm that's a standard format... you echoed that auy?

Comment: I have an `error_log` line that shows the value of eventStartDate immediately before the strtotime line:
`error_log('"' . $eventStartDate . '"');
$eventStart = strtotime($eventStartDate);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I figured it out!* I ran `php -r 'echo date("Y");'` through `strace` and noticed that it was recursively loading time zones. For example:

`openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/zoneinfo/localtime", ...`

eventually followed by

`openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/zoneinfo/localtime/localtime", ...`

and then

`openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/zoneinfo/localtime/localtime/localtime", ...`

You see the pattern. It turns out the problem was I had a symlink in my `/etc/localtime` folder called `localtime` that pointed to... you guessed it: `/etc/localtime`, so it kept loading the time zones over and over again, which explains the CPU usage and continually increasing RAM usage.